# Which type of MATLAB plot would produce spikes on a curve based on certain condition?

Tags: matlab, plot, data-analysis, curve

I have a 29736 x 6 table in MATLAB. The 6th column of the table consists of zeroes and ones. I would like a plot between the Sample No (1 to 29736 of Table) and the 6th column (ones and zeroes), such that there is a nice spike whenever a 1 occurs and a regular curve when 0 occurs. Can someone suggest what line of code/function can do this, and how to systematically go about it?

EDIT:

I used the following code and got an unwanted result (a solid blue block):

```
stem(table_fault_test_data.Fault_Condition, 'Marker', 'none');
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 2]);       % Adjust the y-axis range
```

I basically want to refer to the 6th column of my table which contains ones and zeroes, and plot spikes for only the ones.

Comment: I am not sure of that. Yes, similar to a stem plot maybe, just want spikes at 1s and normal curve at 0s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for a [stem plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html)? You can make one without a marker, so you get spikes for ones and zero for zeroes:

```
data = rand(1, 100) < 0.2;     % Some random sample data
stem(data, 'Marker', 'none');  % Make the stem plot
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 2]);       % Adjust the y-axis range
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get a box kind of blue collar, without any spikes. Please see the edit. I am referring to 6th column of my table. My table has 29736 values, with mix of 1s and 0s in the 6th column, which is Fault_Condition.

Comment: @JoyjitChatterjee: That's probably because you have so many data points along the x-axis that all the spikes are very close together, making it appear to be a solid rectangle. You need to zoom in or limit your x-axis to a smaller part of the data.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. It was helpful!